# Swift 4 Array Find or First

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to perform a filter on an array of structs whereby if the element exists return the element, otherwise return the first element in the array.  At the moment I have a `func` to do this, was wondering if there was a more efficient way.  Predicate or Array extension?

For example, if this is my array of structures and method:

```
struct Person { 
   let name: String
   let age: Int
 }

 let items = [Person(name: "Fred", age: 12), 
              Person(name: "Bill", age: 14), 
              Person(name: "Jane", age: 15), 
              Person(name: "Mary", age: 12)]

 // Find the person based on name, if no match, return first item
 func filterOrFirst(with name: String? = "") -> Person?
 {
    if (items.contains(where: {$0.name == name}))
    {
        return items.first(where: {$0.name == name})
    }
    return items.first
 }

 print(filterOrFirst(with: "Bill"))   // prints Bill 
 print(filterOrFirst())               // prints Fred
```

Comment: You might get more interesting responses on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could also just do `return items.first(where: {$0.name == name}) ?? items.first`, which uses the "nil coalescing operator"

Comment: Basically `first` is always more efficient because `contains` has to check the entire array and `first` has not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
func filterOrFirst(with name: String? = "") -> Person? {
  if let item = items.first(where: {$0.name == name}) {
    return item
  }
  return items.first
}
```

So you need not to traverse complete array two times. You can use ternary operator here. But it increases compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea from this:

```
var arrData:[String] = ["Cat","Dog","Horse","Sheep"]

func respondTheValue(strSearch:String) -> String{

    let stringToSearch = strSearch

    if let index = arrData.index(of: stringToSearch){ //Check if data is present or not
        return arrData[index]
    }else{ // Data not present then return first
        return arrData.first!
    }
}
```

And use it Like:

```
 let responseStr = respondTheValue(strSearch: "Dog")
    print(responseStr) //Case True : Output -- Dog

 let responseStr1 = respondTheValue(strSearch: "Fish")
    print(responseStr1) //Case False : Output -- Cat
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Two *searches*  – `contains` plus `index` –  is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the Note, Have edited the answer, Does that make sense.?

Comment: Yes, but the most efficient way is the suggestion in Aaron's comment. And your code crashes if the array is empty.

Comment: @vadian Completely Agree with that point, will take note in future, Thanks for the suggestion sir.